# Can I have two different polyhedron or polygons that where the sum of the distances from all vertices to all vertices are the same?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

This is a random curiosity I had but couldn't solve, let's say I have a shape in 2D or 3D, and add the distances from all vertices. For example, the square bellow would add up to $5+5+5+5+5\sqrt{2}+5\sqrt{2} = 20 + 10\sqrt{2}$, can I find a different shape with the same number of vertices and the same sum of the distances? On this example would be another quadrilateral that also adds up to $20 + 10\sqrt{2}$

[image]

Comment: Given any two random shapes with same number of vertices, e.g. a square and a tetrahedron. compute the sum of distances and scale one of them to match the other one. Voila, you get two shapes with same number of vertices and sum of distances (e.g a square with side $5$ and a tetrahedron with side $\frac{10+5\sqrt{2}}{3}$).

Comment: true that thanks mate, seems so easy now.